# Validate Public Google calendar url using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have an application accesed by mulitple users that runs FullCalender.
I am giving users the option to sync their FullCalender with their Google Calendar.
If they choose to sync with Google, I ask the user to input their Public Google Calendar Url.
I'd like to validate the google calendar Url using javascipt once the user submits the form.
If the url the user entered does not exist or if the url is not public, I'd like to alert the user the url they provided is invalid or private.
What would the javascript code be for the validation function?

Thank you..

Comment: Can you give an example for such a url? I believe you need to use regualar expressions for this.

Comment: Sure: `https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/test@gmail.com/public/basic`

Comment: I understand what you mean by regular expressions but that's not what I'm after.  I want to know if the url they entered truly exists.